# How to set the href?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, href

I have a button, when pressed has to call a function from an external php file and load it in a new page.

When I click the "SHOW" button on my index.php page, it shows me the message hold in "mesaj", but displays it in index.php page (that I don`t want!).

What I want to accomplish is when I click on the "SHOW" button on my index.php it shows me the content of the message into another php page, named - for eg - content.php. I want to set the href.

**index.php**

```
<input type = "button" class="btn btn-primary" id = "show" onClick = "show()" value = "SHOW"/>
```

**functions.php**

```
function show()
{

    database();

    $sql = "SELECT title FROM `Articles`";

    $titleSql = mysql_query( $sql ) or die("Could not select articles:");

    $html = '<html><body><div class="container"><h2>Basic List Group</h2><ul class="list-group">';

    while ($title = mysql_fetch_array($titleSql)) {
        $html .= '<li class="list-group-item">'.$title["title"].'</li>';
    }

    $html .= '</ul></div></body></html>';

    echo $html;
    //die(json_encode(array("mesaj" => "Entered data successfully ")));

}
```

**function.js**

```
function show(){
        var n = $('#show').val()
        $.post("functions.php", {show:n}).done(function(mesaj){
            //$(document).html(mesaj);
            document.write(mesaj);
        });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " I want to set the href. in my index.php"?

Comment: @amar if I make myself clear :D  <a href="somelink url">alert(mesaj)</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason (apparently) to go from PHP to JS in your case. You'd use `JS $.post` if you need a change of the DOM after it loaded. You can just do this:

```
<a href="function.php" class="btn btn-primary" id="show"/>SHOW</a>
```

This works without going thru JS.

If you want to use BUTTON and go via JS then do this:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="show" value="SHOW"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#show').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'function.php';
});
```

Plain JS:

```
document.getElementById("show").onclick = function(){
    window.location.href = 'function.php';
}
```

As a note, be careful because `<button>` if used inside a form when clicked submits the form. That's why the `e.preventDefault();`

Let's say you have multiple functions in your `function.php` and you need to call one a specific one, I would do this:

***function.php***

```
if(isset($_GET['fn1'])){
    function functionOne(){
      //do something
     }
}

if(isset($_GET['fn2'])){
    function functionTwo(){
       //do something else
    }
}
```

And call it this way:

```
<a href="function.php?fn1" class="btn btn-primary" id="show"/>SHOW</a>
```

or

```
$('#show').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'function.php?fn1';
    //window.location.href = 'function.php?fn2';
});
```

Comment: Tnx, @Mr.Web!

Now the href is set to "function.php" but how do I accomplish my need of writing the php file dynamically ?

If you can see, in "show()" function from my "functions.php" file, i write it dynamically, depending on what enters I have in my database.

Comment: P.S: I don't see any writing in your function.php.... No `show` nor `n` are called inside the show() function.

Comment: $html = '<html><body><div class="container"><h2>Basic List Group</h2><ul class="list-group">';

    while ($title = mysql_fetch_array($titleSql)) {
        $html .= '<li class="list-group-item">'.$title["title"].'</li>';
    }

    $html .= '</ul></div></body></html>';

    echo $html;